# How to get a random character from a span

Tags: javascript

Hi i have created a span element with a text in a containing 0s and 1s. Is there a way which i can randomly select any character in that span element. I know how to do this by putting each character inside a separate span element but i'm creating this for a background and there will be over 2500 0s and 1s.

Html

```
<span class="text" id= "text">0001111011110110101100001</span>
```

JavaScript

```
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length);
```

Comment: so you want to get single charachter from your 0001111011110110101100001 ?

Comment: Strings support array like indexes. How about `text[x]`?

Comment: Use `var text = document.getElementById('text').innerText;` to get the text of span.

Comment: mmh4all yes just one i will running this on a interval so it will happen multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will return a random character from your **span content**

```js
let content = document.querySelector('#text').textContent;

function getRandomChar(str){
  return str.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length));
}

console.log(getRandomChar(content))
```

```html
<!-- I added another content just for better demonstration -->
<span class="text" id="text">00ABCDEFGHIJK</span>
```